# C++ Have Parent Class Function Call Its Child Function

Tags: c++, class, object

I dont know if this is possible or not but say I have a parent class such as

```
class Event {
public:
    virtual void Callback() {
        std::cout << "Basic Event\n";
    }
};
```

and a child class that overrides Callback() like this

```
class PlayerListEvent : public Event {
public:
    std::vector<int> Players;
    void Callback() override {
        std::cout << "Player Event Processing\n";
    }
};
```

and lets say I have a while loop processing the Events from a vector

```
DWORD WINAPI EventHandler(LPVOID lpReserved) {
while (true) {
    for (Event events : _events.EventList) {
        events.Callback();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}

return TRUE;
}
```

how do I make it so when events.Callback is called it doesnt call the function from Event but instead from PlayerListEvent?
Right now its outputting "Basic Event" whenever callback is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get dynamic dispatch if you don't use pointers (or references)

See this code to explain:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Event {
public:
    virtual void Callback() {
        std::cout << "Basic Event\n";
    }
};

class PlayerListEvent : public Event {
public:
    std::vector<int> Players;
    void Callback() override {
        std::cout << "Player Event Processing\n";
    }
};

int main() {
  // Concrete object
  PlayerListEvent e;

  // Concrete object in memory. No dynamic dispatch.
  Event ev = e;
  ev.Callback(); // Prints "Basic event"

  // Pointer!
  Event *evptr = &e;

  // Dynamic dispatch!
  evptr->Callback(); // Prints "Player Event Processing
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly thanks!!

Comment: To be clear, you will also get dynamic dispatch with references, not just pointers (where references are usually implemented with pointers under the hood, but that's not necessary for them to work). `Event& evref = e; evref.Callback();` will work just fine, and is (aside from pathological use), null-safe, where pointers are not.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that is true. However, in the context of the OP's code, `std::vector` can't hold references, unless you use `std::reference_wrapper`, so pointers tend to be easier to use. Just make sure they are handled properly, such as with `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 3):

To maintain polymorphism, you should use references or pointers.

The issue you're encountering is due to slicing. When you copy a derived object into a base object, only the base part is copied and the derived part is discarded. This is why you're seeing `"Basic Event"` instead of `"Player Event Processing"`.

Here's the modified code:

```
DWORD WINAPI EventHandler(LPVOID lpReserved) {
    while (true) {
        for (Event& event : _events.EventList) {
            event->Callback();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

i changed `Event events` to `Event& event`. That way, `event` is a reference in `EventList`, not a copy of it. This way, when you call `Callback()`, the correct version is called.

Comment: Note that the proposed change to use `Event&` will only work if `_events` is a `vector<PlayerEventList>` and not  a `vector<Event>`

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing object slicing. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958364/a-way-how-to-overcome-object-slicing) for more details.

For the sake of simplyfing your problem, let me work on the following code; it prints `Basic event`:

```cpp
PlayerListEvent ple;
Event e = ple; //Sliced
for (auto event : { e }) {
    event.Callback();
}
```

Pointers solve the issue:

```cpp
PlayerListEvent ple;
Event* e = &ple; //Now a pointer
for (auto event : { e }) {
    event->Callback();
}
```

References also solve the issue but need a [reference wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to be stored in a container.

```cpp
PlayerListEvent ple;
Event& e = ple; //Now a reference
for (auto event : { std::reference_wrapper(e) }) {
    event.get().Callback();
}
```

Note:
Had `Event::Callback` been a pure virtual method, your compiler would have prevented this situation, by warning that you are instanciating an abstract class.
This can be an efficient way to catch object slicing.

Comment: lets say down the road I add more data to the Event class, would it be wise to stick to it as a pointer or a reference?

Comment: More than the members you add to the class, what is really going to matter is how objects get created / destroyed. Without seeing the rest of your code, the "safe" answer I can give is: as long as you manage [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13852710/20143744) cleanly, pointers will be easier to use in regard of object lifetime. However, as is noted by ShadowRanger in his comment to another answer, you will need to test for `nullptr` before calling `Callback`.